# Way to View embedded video in Tumblr dashboard?

Tags: youtube, tumblr, video, embed, video-streaming

Is there any way to embed a YouTube video into a Tumblr text post to make the video playable from the dashboard? It seems the default (unless making a separate video post per video) is just to display a little grey box with a permalink to the original post:
[image]

It's the same for both new and old embed codes, seems pretty annoying. Any way to either upload to the tumblr host and embed as their own video format or at least show a preview...? Putting a still picture with a link isn't what I'm looking for either... The video looks/plays fine on the blog post just not on the dashboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asked the support team, not allowed in the current API